# JDBC using default callable statement parameter

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a procedure I'm calling using a JDBC callable statement. The first parameter, `v_type`, has a default value I want to use. The proc/code is simplified.

```
PROCEDURE select_type(v_type   IN     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'All',
                      cv_1     OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
   IF (v_type = 'All')
   THEN
      OPEN cv_1 FOR
         SELECT DISTINCT TYPE,
           FROM type_source;
   ELSE
      IF (v_type = 'NotAll')
      THEN
         OPEN cv_1 FOR
            SELECT DISTINCT type, desc,
              FROM OTHER_TYPE_SOURCE;
   END IF;
END;
```

This is the code I attempted, assuming null would trigger the default.

```
callablestatement = connection.prepareCall("{ CALL select_type(?,?) } ") ;
callablestatement.setString(1, null);
callablestatement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
callablestatement.execute();
resultset = (ResultSet)callablestatement.getObject(2);
```

The last line `.getObject()` throws a cursor closed exception, presumably, due to the null parameter not matching the `IF` structure in the procedure and the cursor never being opened.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11881259/2231632

Comment: I think you are correct, it is a duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How in JDBC can you call a stored procedure procudure when only setting some parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880517/how-in-jdbc-can-you-call-a-stored-procedure-procudure-when-only-setting-some-par)

Comment: Your comment might be a duplicate of the one 2 comments above it..